# WebGrid pager styling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

Is there any way to apply styling to the WebGrid Pager?

The only way I've found to do this is from client side by writing Jquery code,
but it seems a little bit dirty.

Is there any normal way to provide css for this GridHelper?

Comment: The pager created have some classes created along with it, you can use these classes to style it.

Comment: No classes created just pure <a href="">1</a>

Comment: try using jquery to find these <a> tags and surround them by divs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CSS as normal for styling links in a pager. You just need to ensure that you can identify the links via a CSS selector. If you place you Pager call in an identifiable element, this is quite easy:

```
<div id="pager">
    @grid.Pager()
</div>
```

Now you can access the links for styling:

```
#pager a {
    color: pink;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#pager a:hover {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simple with css. 
[image]

Set your footer style to `table-pager`

```cs
@grid.GetHtml(
  mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
  columns: gridColumns,
  tableStyle: "table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive table-hover",
  rowStyle: "table-row-clickable",
  footerStyle: "table-pager"
)
```

and add this css:

```
.table-pager > td {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

  .table-pager > td > a {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
  }

  .table-pager > td > a:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
```